# ASP.net Update Panel is losing all styles and jquery binded plugins

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Upon UpdatePanel refresh of asp.net all the css styles and jquery plugins such as chosen dropdown everything is completely getting lost.

We have used this UpdatePanel in so many places.

So is their any way of an global approach to solve this if someone have come across the problem

**Note: We are loading all the pages in iframe for security issues. Is that the problem?**

Please find the Reference Images:

**On First Load:**
[image]

**On UpdatePanel Refresh:**
[image]

Comment: You need to call the _js-inside-your-`document.ready`_ after updatepanel refresh (via `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`

Comment: @mshsayem - can you share some piece of code plz and how about css styles. Do i need to reload all?